# How to target tree elements using external commands in nightwatch.js?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am looking for advice on how best to structure all the moving parts to get my nightwatch.js tests setup correctly using custom commands. I want to abstract out a command to load a dropdown menu, by putting it outside the page object, but it only works when I move the elements out of the tree section. How do I include the tree elements in the abstraction below - stuck atm. Thanks,

So my tests looks like this -

```
'xyz': function (client) {
    var page = client.page.myPage();

    page
        .setDropDownButtonValue(page, '@createBtn', 'New Folder')
        .api.useCss()
        .waitForElementVisible('[placeholder="New Folder Name"]', 3000)
        .setValue('[placeholder="New Folder Name"]', 'Whatever');
}
```

and my custom command - setDropDownButtonValue - looks like this

```
exports.command = function (scope, button, value) {

var xpathMatch = '//*[text()="' + value + '"]';

scope
    .waitForElementVisible(button, 5000)
    .click(button)
    .waitForElementVisible('@dropdownMenu', 5000)
    .api.useXpath();

return scope.
     waitForElementVisible(xpathMatch, 5000)
     .click(xpathMatch);
```

};

And myPage object looks like this -

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
sections: {
    tree: {
        selector: '.drive-tree-container'
        elements: {
            createBtn: { selector: '[data-bind*="_onCreateActionClick"]' },
            dropdownMenu: { selector: '[data-bind*="element: menuDOM"].dropdown-menu.create-menu' }
        }
    }
},

elements: {
    tree: { selector: '.drive-tree-container' }
}
```

};

The above unit test only works when I remove the tree section -

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
elements: {
    createBtn: { selector: '[data-bind*="_onCreateActionClick"]' },
    dropdownMenu: { selector: '[data-bind*="element: menuDOM"].dropdown-menu.create-menu' }
}
```

};